# Selenium Webdriver c# without waiting for page to load

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following scenario:

I want to navigate to a page. Then click a button as soon as it appears(not wait for page to load ). I don't want to wait for the initial page to load as it takes a long time. My program currently is stuck until the page loads and then clicks the button.

I basically want to navigate to link and then have no wait for page and continue with my code.

Is there anyway round this?

Answer (score 3):

With the latest version of the .NET bindings, you can set a page load timeout. However, there are some caveats you'll need to be aware of. First, this hasn't been implemented by all browsers. It should work for IE and Firefox, if memory serves. Secondly, you'll need to catch an exception to make that work properly, but it can be done.

```
// WARNING! Completely untested code written without
// the benefit of an IDE!
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

try
{
    driver.Url = "http://your.long.loading.page.com";
}
catch (TimeoutException) 
{
    // NOTE: In 2.26 or later, this will be WebDriverTimeoutException
}

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement element = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) => 
{
    return d.FindElement(By.Id("yourId"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Url = "http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading";
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
{
    return d.FindElement(By.Id("someDynamicElement"));
});
```

It does exactly what you want. It queries the page to find the element, catches exceptions if no element found and returns an element when found.

After that, you can manipulate the button ignoring the fact that page can be not loaded

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Selenium is by default trying to simulate the **real user** - I know that it kinda sucks, especially at a times you need to test a deploy after deploy after deploy...

But: If real user has to wait for button to appear, then the program has to do it also...

BTW: If the button really appears among first on the page, you can try this:

1. search for the button by ID, xpath ... the way you do it
2. Catch exception (I am Java guy, so dont ask me how)
3. If there was error, wait short time (e.g. 200 milliseconds) and then go to 1
4. If not, click the button
5. The cycle should end also if certain amount of time passes (10s) and if so, throw exception

As stated above: Language of my choice is Java. There I can do that. But I dont know how to write that in C#