# How to "block" an AJAX response using Selenium

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, unit-testing, selenium

In summary, what I'm trying to do is "open" a page `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://somepage.com")` and then **immediately** block the response from `"http://somepage.com/something.asmx/GetStuff"` so that I can verify that some element has some class before the response is loaded: `driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("buttom.some-button")).GetAttribute("class").Contains("disabled")` and then the `disabled`.

Is something like this possible, and if so, how do I go about it?

My question is similar to [Selenium Webdriver c# without waiting for page to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922823/selenium-webdriver-c-sharp-without-waiting-for-page-to-load) in what it's trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't think you can use Selenium for that, but paired with FiddlerCore it should be doable - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541499/how-to-capture-http-request-using-fiddlercore-in-c/26323323#26323323

Answer (score 0):

Cast your instance of IWebDriver (FirefoxDriver, ChromeDriver, etc) to `IJavacriptExecutor` and replace the jQuery `$.ajax()` method with a stub, such as:

```
var driver = Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor

driver.ExecuteScript("window.originalAjax = $.ajax")
driver.ExecuteScript("$.ajax = function() {}")

// navigate to page, check class

driver.ExecuteScript("$.ajax = window.originalAjax")
```

So when your request calls into `$.ajax` it will hit a blank method.

This has the downside that you cannot easily get the request to 'continue' after blocking it, as no request was ever created. You would have to refresh the page without doing the above steps which could give some sort of false positive.