# How to navigate to a page in Selenium without waiting for AJAX responses

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, testing, automated-tests

How the page I'm trying to test works is

1. Open page
2. A button is supposed to be disabled
3. An AJAX request that was sent on page load finishes
4. The button is enabled

However, when I try to do something like

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://thepage.com"); 
Assert.IsFalse(driver.FindElement(By.Id("the-button")).IsEnabled());
```

the problem is that the AJAX request has finished between the first and second lines and therefore I can't properly test that the button is disabled at first. Is there any way to do a `Navigate().GoToUrlWithoutWaitingForAnything` or any hack I could use to do this test?

Comment: My apologies, I misread the question. I don't think a selenium test would be a good option for this. As far as I know there isn't a way to choose a spot to pause the application from loading. If this is necessary I would use some approach that actually has access to the application code. I'll delete my answer since it doesn't apply.

Comment: Are you posting as two different users? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863476/how-to-block-an-ajax-response-using-selenium